# Problem in integration question

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^{\pi} e^{2 x} \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\,dx$$

in this I have tried to substitute $x$ by $\pi -t$
and thought about it but after that got stuck.

Comment: What does that substitution do here to facilitate?  Why not integrate by parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Considering the problem of the antiderivative first, making $x+\frac \pi 4=t$ leads to $$\int e^{2 x} \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\,dx=e^{-\frac{\pi }{2}} \int e^{2 t} \sin (t)\,dt$$ Now consider $$\sin(t)=\frac{e^{it}-e^{it}}{2i}$$ which makes $$e^{2 t} \sin (t)=\frac i 2(e^{(2-i) t}-e^{(2+i) t})$$ and remember that $$\int e^{at}\,dt=\frac 1a e^{at}$$ I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: the answer will be in terms if $i$

Comment: @hey. Which will simplify to a real expression

Comment: Nice method . I found this vefy useful .

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to handle this problem. One way is to use $\sin(A+B)=\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$ and so applying that on the sine term in your integral, we get $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+x)=\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\cos x+\cos\frac{\pi}{4}\sin x=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(\cos x+\sin x)$. So actually, your integral now becomes of the form $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\int(e^{2x}\sin x+e^{2x}\cos x)dx$. When you split those in two, both are staple integrals for Integration by Parts (IBP). In fact, when IBP is used on the term $e^{2x}\sin x$ twice, the other integral can be found as well. I don't want to spoil the fun here, so...give it a try from here.

Answer (score 1):

Why $\pi - t$ instead of $\frac{\pi}{4} - t$? Do you know this [site](http://www.integral-calculator.com/)?

Comment: If the OP knows that site you are referring to, what's the point of posting the question on this site?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

Let $U=\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2t}\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+t) \, dt$

Write $\sin(\frac{\pi}{4}+t)$ as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin t+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos t$.

Let $B_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2t}\sin t \, dt$ and let $B_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{2t}\cos t \, dt$.
Using integration by parts $\sqrt{2}B_1=\frac{1}{5}(1-e^{4\pi})$ and in a similar way $\sqrt{2}B_2=\frac{2}{5}(-1+e^{4\pi})$. Thus $\sqrt{2}(B_1+B_2)=\frac{1}{5}e^{4\pi}-\frac{1}{5}$. So $(B_1+B_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(\frac{1}{5}e^{4\pi}-\frac{1}{5})$. Lastly note $U=B_1+B_2$.